# Is it OK to use a doubled key for XTS-AES?

Tags: aes, xts

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory#Xor%E2%80%93encrypt%E2%80%93xor_(XEX) reads:

> The standard supports using a different key for the IV encryption than
> for the block encryption; this is contrary to the intent of XEX and
> seems to be rooted in a misinterpretation of the original XEX paper,
> but does not harm security.[11][7] As a result, users wanting AES-256
> and AES-128 encryption must supply 512 bits and 256 bits of key
> respectively.

Does this means that it's OK to give XTS a "doubled" key - i.e. its two halves being identical?

Comment: I think the question becomes "OK to who?". Reading the text in your question I would say that it is OK with regards to security of the algorithm. However, key material should consist of randomized (and thus independent) bits, and it may therefore not be OK to an organization that requires IEEE P1619...